# compass:dist & execFile("compass.bat", ...) - Warning: spawn EPERM

Tags: ruby, node.js, gruntjs, webstorm, compass

First of all, I am pretty new to (modern) web development and I tried to import an existing project into my WebStorm and run a Grunt task.

It stops at "compass:dist" with:

```
$ node.exe C:\Users\lgr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt --gruntfile C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\Gruntfile.js buildall
    Initializing
Command-line options: --gruntfile=C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\Gruntfile.js, --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.

Registering "grunt-bump" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-bump\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-bump\package.json...OK
Loading "bump.js" tasks...OK
+ bump, bump-commit, bump-only

Registering "grunt-html2js" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-html2js\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-html2js\package.json...OK
Loading "html2js.js" tasks...OK
+ html2js

Registering "grunt-contrib-clean" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-clean\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-clean\package.json...OK
Loading "clean.js" tasks...OK
+ clean

Registering "grunt-contrib-copy" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-copy\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-copy\package.json...OK
Loading "copy.js" tasks...OK
+ copy

Registering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-concat\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-concat\package.json...OK
Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
+ concat

Registering "grunt-contrib-cssmin" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-cssmin\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-cssmin\package.json...OK
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...OK
+ cssmin

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-contrib-jshint" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-jshint\package.json...OK
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...OK
+ jshint

Registering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-uglify\package.json...OK
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...OK
+ uglify

Registering "grunt-karma" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-karma\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-karma\package.json...OK
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...OK
+ karma

Registering "grunt-conventional-changelog" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-conventional-changelog\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-conventional-changelog\package.json...OK
Loading "changelog.js" tasks...OK
+ changelog

Registering "grunt-ngdocs" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-ngdocs\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-ngdocs\package.json...OK
Loading "grunt-ngdocs.js" tasks...OK
+ ngdocs

Registering "grunt-contrib-compass" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\package.json...OK
Loading "compass.js" tasks...OK
+ compass

Registering "grunt-contrib-requirejs" local Npm module tasks.
Reading C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-requirejs\package.json...OK
Parsing C:\Users\lgr\workspace\js\rit-workshop\ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-requirejs\package.json...OK
Loading "requirejs.js" tasks...OK
+ requirejs
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
- watch
+ BuildCommit, after-test, archive, archiveNONmin, buildall, buildjs, buildjsCommit, buildjsNONmin, buildjsNONminCommit, css, cssmy, default, delta, incrementBuild, shell, templates, test, watch

Running tasks: buildall

Running "buildall" task

Running "clean:buildall" (clean) task
Verifying property clean.buildall exists in config...OK
Files: [no src]
Options: force=false, no-write=false
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "css" task

Running "compass" task

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.dist exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: config="config.rb"
Warning: spawn EPERM Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I tried googling a bit, but all I seem to get is that this is a permission error, but I don't know where to start to fix it.

I tried cleaning the project, reinstalling Ruby for Windows, reinstalling compass inside of ruby. Nothing worked.

## Update:

I tried debugging the build and in file `bin-version\index.js` the line

```
execFile(bin, ['--version'], function (err, stdout, stderr) {
```

seems to throw the error as the debugger wouldn't go beyond this point. The `bin` is `compass.bat` and it looks like the build has some permission error? When I open my `cmd` and type `"compass --version"` it just works fine. I have the ruby/bin in my classpath aswell where the compass.bat is placed.

```
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Verifying property compass.dist exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: config="config.rb"
Warning: spawn EPERM Use --force to continue.
```

Does anyone know about what could cause this error?

Comment: Run your gruntfile with "--verbose" to see on which file the EPERM problem occurs.

Comment: @PeteTNT Thanks for your comment. I edited the question with the --verbose output. Unfortunately I still can't tell where the error occurs.

Comment: what Node version do you use? Try debugging your grun task toi see where the error comes from: create a Node.js run configuration like the following:

Working directory: the directory where your Grunfile.js is located.
Javascript file: C:\Users\lgr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt.  Application parameters: grunt tasks to run.

 Add breakpoints to your Gruntfile.js, start debugging

Comment: Hello @lena, I setup a node.js run config like you said, but I don't know where to set my breakpoints? The error is thrown in task `'css'`, which is registered by `grunt.registerTask('css', ['compass']);` compass is initialized by `compass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                }
            }
        },`

Comment: try setting breakpoints in your_project\node_modules\grunt-contrib-compass\tasks\lib\compass.js. In exports.buildConfigContext function. seems grunt is trying to create a temporary config.rb somewhere in your tmp directory and fails because of lack of permissions

Comment: hi @lena, thanks for your help so far. I debugged the build process a bit and I think the err is thrown in file `bin-version\index.js` at line `execFile(bin, ['--version'], function (err, stdout, stderr) {` where the `bin` is `"compass.bat"`. When I open a standard cmd I can type `compass --version` and it just works fine. Do you have any idea probably? It doesn't go beyond that point. After that the console throws: `Fatal error: spawn EPERM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this, but I can't tell exactly what caused it. What I can say is that it has nothing to do with compass itself, wrong permissions or Windows - it has to do with a wrong project setup. So, if you get this error, check your setup and if every dependency is available.